# What's the story behind Erik Dommel's kid?

Tags: yamato-2199

Very briefly in episode 20 (of the 2012 Xebec/AIC remake "Yamato 2199") you see a flashback of Erik Dommel's wife and a toddler. I not only assume it is his, I also assume something happened and it's this kid that is buried under the grave he meets his wife at in episode 11 after being awarded the Special First Class Dessler Cross.

What happened? Has it something to do with his wife getting involved in the rebellion against Dessler? (I can't read Garmillan, but the flowers are in the way anyway.)